# presentmodalviewcontroller navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone

I am creating a Navigation based iPhone application.

In that I have called a `UiViewController` using `presentModalViewController`. After that, the ViewController becomes visible. From that ViewController I need to call another ViewController using the sample `presentModalViewController`. Is this possible or not?

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear than that if you want a relevant answer.

Comment: @Jeevanantham: Yes it's possible, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "call another uiviewcontroller"? (It really helps if you can be more detailed in your question.) If you mean, "slide in another view controller", then:

```
MyNewViewController *myNewViewController = [[MyNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewViewController" bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:myNewViewController animated:YES];
[myNewViewController release];
```

...where:

- `MyNewViewController` is the new view controller class that you want to slide in (the above code assumes you have an XIB file for the view controller class).
- `navigationController` points to the current navigation controller. You'll have to replace it with something like `[self navigationController]`, depending where you are in the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

U might be using following line to present a view controller.

```
//assume name of viewController which u want to present is "myViewController"
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES]
```

If you want to push an other ViewController or present an other ViewController then u will need to replace above line with following lines.

```
//[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; //if u want to show navigation bar then remove this line
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

After using above code you can present or push other view controllers within presented view controller.

Hope it will solve your problem :)